How to solve this functional equation in a nice way?
I have an equation:
$$\frac{h(e^x)}{h(x)} = e^x$$
I want to find the nicest way of solving this for $h$. Preferably an analytic solution. The best thing I was able to find yet is this (sorry for image, couldn't get \cases to work here):

Unfortunately, this solution is not even continuously differentiable.
For the context I will provide why do I need to solve this in the first place. Lets define such a function $f(x, n)$, where $x \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$, that $f(x, 0) = x$ and $f(x, n + 1) + e^{f(x, n)}$. I. e. $f(x, n)$ is $n$-folded exponent of $x$. I was trying to generalize this function for a real $\alpha$ instead of $n$. Here is what I have found. Following equations obviously should hold: $f(x, \alpha + 1) = e^{f(x, \alpha)} = f(e^x, \alpha)$, $f(f(x, \alpha), \beta) = f(x, \alpha + \beta)$. It turns out that in order to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}$ we only need to know the value of $f$ itself (without knowing it's arguments). This holds since
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}f(x, \alpha) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}\left(f(x, \alpha + \delta)\right)\big|_{\delta=0} = $$
$$= \frac{\partial}{\partial\delta}\left(f(f(x, \alpha), \delta)\right)\big|_{\delta=0}$$
Thus we calculated $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}$ by plugging (in place of $x$) the value of $f$ into the derivative of $f$ by $\alpha$ at $\alpha = 0$. Knowing this fact I denoted $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}f(x, \alpha) = h(f(x, \alpha))$. Knowing $h$ it's possible to retrieve $f(x, \alpha)$ by solving a Cauchy problem. Also $h(e^{f(x, \alpha)}) = h(f(x, \alpha + 1)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}f(x, \alpha + 1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}e^{f(x, \alpha)} = e^{f(x, \alpha)}\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}f(x, \alpha) = e^{f(x, \alpha)}h(f(x, \alpha))$. This is where the original equation comes from. As it turns out, the fact that a function solves this equation is nearly enough for it to be the function $h$ that I'm looking for. And what I mean by that is that the only thing left to do will be to multiply that solution by a correct coefficient to get true $h$. I won't share a proof here since it's not even a part of the question.

@Servaes thanks for suggestion. Yes, that question seems to be similar to mine. But there is no actual beautiful answer. Suggestion to build  the function from arbitrary definition on an interval is what I used in my solution. But I'm looking for something smooth and mathematically beautiful (whatever that means)

@Усердныйбобёр   There exists usually no such easy closed form with this kind of functional equations.
